# Paypal error on ExecutePayment with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, paypal

I've taken a project already done by another developer but unfinished and full of bugs. In this project I have a PayPal integration that uses the PayPal (2.0.0-rc2).
I have the PayPalAccountId and the PayPalClientSettings in the configuration settings and I fill it with the data of the live environment taken from Paypal developer site.
I have some code that initializes the PayPalHttpClient setup and the transaction (put the correct amount) and sends to PayPal, I suppose it follows [this example](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues/355#issuecomment-389960130).
Everything works, the user goes to PayPal and if he cancels he comes back to the correct url, but if the user logs in to his paypal account and makes the payment PayPal goes back into my code exactly at this point:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> PayPalReturnCallback(string paymentId, string token, string payerId)
{
    try
    {
        var payPalManager = PayPalManager.GetInstance(_payPalConfig);
        var paymentUrl = await payPalManager.ExecutePayment(paymentId, payerId);
    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("PaymentFailed","Checkout",new {paymentId, ex.Message});
    }

    Order order = new Order(_orderDl);
    await order.LoadOrderByPayPalCode(paymentId);
    order.ExecutePaymentTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
    await order.Save();

    return RedirectToAction("PaymentSuccess","Checkout",new { order.Id});
}
```

and throws an exception when it arrives to method payPalManager.ExecutePayment with this message:

> One or more errors occurred. ({"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"})

but the client authentication is fine also because otherwise it wouldn't connect with PayPal the first time. I thing that somehow the "token" parameter coming back should be used, but I don't know where.

Any help is more than appreciated

Comment: from my understanding, i see that you are using the production / live paypal configuration in your application, what happens if you run the app in `debug` mode, did you try running the app in the `release` mode or use the test mode in paypal configuration and use the test credentials.

Comment: I try and it functions until it arrive to login for the user...the behavior should de different?!? It should arrive to complete the payment?

Comment: may be the arguments to the paypal application like the user token, email etc are not being passed, i guess, its been a very long time i did paypal integration, however i think that they pass you back the authorization codes after the user first authorizes your application in paypal.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the solution. In this library there TWO place where the developer has to specify that is not anymre in sandbox (or in production) area, the first is when it create the request and the second when it make the final payment. Change that the client error disappear.